# Repository pattern + Combine

Tags: ios, swift

Looking for some feedback on the repository pattern. I've come up with this interface:

```
protocol PersonRepository {
  var people: AnyPublisher<[Person], Never> { get }
  func update()
}
```

The object that uses this repository subscribes to the `people` publisher for updates. When it needs the update, calling `update()` would trigger the repository to do a fetch of people data somewhere - be it as a long lasting network operation or I/O operations.

Does this make sense? What other approaches are there in the same vein as this?